# Restrict User Functions to only "su" to other users

Tags: linux, centos, su, access-control

I have a server running on `CentOS 7` that have 100 user each user with restricted access to its home dir. I want to create a user that only able to `su` to one of these other users, where all other commands are restricted.

Restricting the other commands can be achieved by [rbash](https://www.tecmint.com/rbash-a-restricted-bash-shell-explained-with-practical-examples/), however, `su - user1` is not working unless the switch user is member of user1 group, and due to linux limitations I can't add a single user to 100 different group.

**UPDATE:**

Elaborating more, switch user `swuser` should be able to switch to any of the 100 users `userX` only, and can't switch to user `root`

Any workaround to handle this?

Comment: Write script that do checks and commands you need and allow execute it by a specific user via sudo as root

Answer (score 0):

Both parts of the question should be possible to solve by adding proper entries in `/etc/sudoers` file by command `visudo` issued from the root account.

There you can allow or disallow users to have access to other accounts.

Comment: You have to be more specific, do you have answer that does the job? if yes, list it in details.

Comment: @Eng7 Take a look at this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/767415/limit-user-to-execute-selective-commands-linux